# If $Ax = b$ and $y := Tx$, what are the constraints for valid $y$'s?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have an underdetermined, rectangular matrix $A$ and vector $b$. I want to reason about the space where $Ax = b$ and specifically the projection $y:= Tx$. Is there a way to describe the space of $y$'s that satisfy the constraint $Ax = b$? My intuition is this should also be a linearly constrained space in the dimensionality of $y$.

I.e., how do I express constraints that define the space $\{y | \exists x, Ax = b, y = Tx \}$?

Comment: What projection? Where is $T$ coming from?

Comment: $T$ is another arbitrary rectangular matrix. So $A$, $b$, and $T$ are given.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y=\{y | \exists x, Ax = b, y = Tx \}$.

If $b \notin {\cal R}A$, then $Y=\emptyset$, otherwise let $x_0$ be such that
$Ax_0 = b$.

Then $Y = \{ T(x_0+x) | x \in \ker A\} = \{T x_0\} + T \ker A$.